# “It expires…” vs “It would expire by 31 Oct”

Tags: tenses, present-tense, will-would

> Your collected Amazon Pay offer for Swiggy **would expire** by
>   31-Oct-2018.

Please help me understand why 'would' is used in the place of 'will'. Also, can we not use the **simple present** here that roughly translates to below sentence?

> Your collected Amazon Pay offer for Swiggy **expires** by 31-Oct-2018

Comment: Best include the link where this message is included, unless it arrived by email. Did it? Is this message from an American/British/German/Spanish/Italian etc. Amazon?

Comment: This looks like it's missing a part, something like "**If you pay*** XX blah blah your collected Amazon blah blah **would** expire blah blah...."

Comment: Yes, there is an *if* implied. It doesn't need to be stated explicitly but it has to be implied by whatever comes before this phrase. What does come before this sentence? We need the context please. If you can't explain this word choice given the context that you have, we certainly can't explain it when given no context whatsoever. For all we can tell, it could simply be a typo, or a bug.

Comment: Yes. I received this message from Amazon as an email with the above sentence in the email body...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the expiration is a **certainty**, then "will" (rather than the subjunctive "would") can be correct:

> Your offer will expire by 31-Oct-2018.

or

> Your offer will expire on 31-Oct-2018.

("Expire by" implies some uncertainty in the date that the offer will expire-- it could be sooner than 31 October.)

It is also acceptable to use the simple present, as you suggest:

> Your offer expires on 31-Oct-2018.

**This is the best wording** -- simple is often best.

It's difficult to construct a scenario where "would expire" is correct, because it implies **uncertainty** that the expiration will happen.  Even these uncertain scenarios are better with "will" rather than would:

> We have sent your bid to Alice.  If Alice fails to respond, your offer will expire on 31-October-2018.
>
> Some states have time limits on gift cards.  If this applies to you, your offer will expire on 31-October-2018.

The scenario has to be very uncertain for "would" to make sense:

> Alice sent a letter to Bob.  If Alice's letter is delayed more than a week, your offer would expire before Bob receives the letter.

Comment: I would go further  with the *expire by*. That is completely wrong unless there is uncertainty—so you could actually use it in the last example, and *by* is often taken to mean "by the beginning of" so I would understand that I would wake up on the morning of 31-Oct and find it had already expired. You can use *by* where you are not sure or there is variety, so "Everything in my fridge has different dates but it will all expire by 31-Oct" or  "I'm not sure but it definitely expires by 31-Oct".